# Conversion of energy to power in a cavity

Tags: optics, energy

Suppose I have a cavity and I fill it up with photons. Let's assume the cavity is in steady state. Multiplying the number of photons with the photon energy gives me the total energy stored inside the cavity. How do I convert this to the total power stored inside the cavity?

I know that P=dW/dt, but what is t in this case?

Comment: $t$ is time. What do you think power is? How is it related to energy?

Comment: I'm aware that t is time, but what exactly is this time quantity? Is it the round-trip time of the cavity? Is it the photon-decay time? Or is it something else?

Comment: The only sensible thing in this context is, the rate at which work is being done on charges within the volume. Or the rate at which energy flows past a certain surface area in question. "Power" stored, doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Power is the rate of change of energy, or the speed of a flow or transfer of energy.

Power isn't stored, so the power stored inside the cavity is zero.

If there was a hole in the cavity, with photons going in or out, then the power going through the hole would be the rate of change of the energy inside - so if 1J of energy left through the hole in 1s, the power would be 1W. If 10J left in 2s, the power would be 5W. In each of those, power=energy/time, the time is how long the power is flowing for.